# Calculating sum of all permutations

Tags: combinatorics

Given a number n. If we generate all the permutation from 1 to n, for a permutation $P_i, F(P_i)$ is defined as 
$\sum(|P_i - i|)$ for i = 1 to n. So
if n = 3, for the permutation 1 3 2

F = |1-1| + |3-2| + |2-3| = 2

and for permutation 3 1 2

F = |3-1| + |1-2| + |2-3|

Now we need to find the sum of all F for a given n.

I realize that there is a particular pattern here.
For say n = 3;
F values are

0,2,2,4,4,4 which sums to 16

and for n = 4 the first six values are same and then there is a new series.
F values for n = 4 are

0 2 2 4 4 4 2 4 4 6 6 6 4 6 4 6 8 8 6 6 6 6 8 8 which sums to 120 
and so on.
How can I generalize it to find the sum for any n?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\sigma_1$, ..., $\sigma_{n!}$ denote the $n!$ permutations, so that you want to evaluate the sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n!} \sum_{i=1}^n |\sigma_k(i)-i|.
$$
Switching the order of summation yields the equal expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{n!} |\sigma_k(i)-i|.
$$
For each fixed $i$ and any given possible value $1\le j\le n$, there are exactly $(n-1)!$ permutations $\sigma$ that send $i$ to $j$. Therefore this sum equals
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (n-1)! \sum_{j=1}^{n} |j-i|.
$$
And this can be shown to equal $(n-1)! (n^3-n)/3$.